# Cygwin: readline lib loaded in different locations

Tags: bash, cygwin

Within cygwin, almost each unix command I type prints a warning message, takes time and eventually gives a correct result:

```
-bash-4.1$ ls
0 [main] bash 7468 child_info_fork::abort: cygreadline7.dll: Loaded to different address:
parent(0x320000) != child(0x3B0000)
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

What is the meaning of this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows loads each dynamic library at the same address in every process. This interacts badly with Cygwin's emulation of `fork` when there are different versions of a DLL in the parent and child process (i.e. when you upgraded a DLL between the time the parent started and the time the child started). Restart all your Cygwin processes after upgrading a library.

Comment: I had a similar failure with cmake "cygkrb5-3.dll loaded to different address" (then died).  For some reason restarting cygwin wasn't enough I had to reinstall cygwin and the problem went away. Odd.

Answer (score 3):

The [Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures) mentions "resource temporarily unavailable" as one of the error messages that can occur because of the way Windows handles process creation. The potential solutions it lists are:

- Restart the process
- Remove all applications [known to conflict with Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures)
- Follow the instructions in `/usr/share/doc/rebase/README` to run `rebaseall`